# How do I get an entire team to have the exact same settings in Visual Studio so that each dev has the same prerequisites and settings to work from?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, ide, settings

Our team is transitioning from a domain specific vb basic type of workflow to WPF in Visual Studio. This is new to us and we are running into issues before we even get into coding. This new setup has multiple nuget, .net, and dll prerequisites to build correctly.

Is there a way for a fully fleshed out IDE to export all the dependencies, settings, and structure of the project so that new devs do not need to rebuild the 'house of cards', but rather get handed an IDE that can allow for them to get productive right away?

Comment: Do you want to use Visual Basic or c# to develop WPF projects? WPF applications and WPF applications (.NET framework) of Visual Basic and c# are available in Visual Studio. There are the TargetFramework, Reference, OutputType , Assembly name and so on of the program in the .vbproj (Visual Basic) and .csproj (c#) files. You could try to synchronize the environment configuration of each developer by setting .vbproj (Visual Basic) and .csproj (c#) files.

Comment: We are using C#. I will take a look at the .csproj file...thanks!